# Multiple @Id fields / keys on entity

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have one primary key (Integer) on my entities, but I also have a UUID on those entities that I do a lot of searches on. I am wondering if it is possible to make that UUID a key as well, so that Hibernate (or whatever) does not have to fetch the entity from database each time, but can check its cache first instead?

Comment: Hibernate has two different kinds of caches that may be useful.  The L2 (shared) cache, which is keyed off of @Id, and the query cache, which would cache query results of find-by-value operations.  It sounds like both of these working together may give you what you want.

Comment: Ah, thats right. Is there any way to pre-populate the L2 cache? Lets say if all Entities are fetched by a select query, then fetched one-by-one using their uuid - I would like to eliminate those one-by-one fetches.

Comment: Do you Spring maybe or will you consider using it? Because Spring provides caching mechanism not by primary key, as Hibernate does, but by any value, you could specify your UUID here.
Also you can implement your own caching mechanism in Hibernate, but that is reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I do use Spring, so I have been thinking of using that cache support - but I was hoping hibernate/JPA had something that would be suitable already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Hibernate.  But if you use EclipseLink in the 2.4 release there is support for cache indexes on non-id fields.  Then any query using the UUID will be able to obtain cache hits.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Indexes

Comment: This is great. Unfortunately it seems hibernate does not have this :/